# Changing context/scope of Ember.ComputedProperty

Tags: javascript, ember.js, binding, scope, computed-properties

As the title said, I wish to find a way to change the context or scope of Ember.ComputedProperty.

My use case is that I allow user to define a bindingConfig property which is used for dynamic binding. This bindingConfig can be either a string or a function or an Ember.ComputedProperty.

Because the bindingConfig is passed in separate from the Content/Model, thus I need to bind it to the content and I haven't found anyway of doing this for Ember.ComputedProperty.

https://ember-twiddle.com/8c01af57f3a3b9fde858?openFiles=application.controller.js%2Capplication.template.hbs

Many thanks, :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. What does `bindingConfig` return and what is the behavior you expect?

Comment: bindingConfig can be one of the three type: "String", "function", "Ember.ComputedProperty". I expect the get-prop helper to be able to get the correct property in each case.

So if, it is a string, simply do "content.get(bindingConfig)" to get the content property.

However, if bindingConfig is an Ember.ComputedProperty, I expect it to return what ever is inside its function, but with the context as the item in the list.

The link I provided contains a more detail example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your example shows:

```
{{my-component content=appObj bindingConfig="name"}}
{{my-component content=appObj bindingConfig=nickName}}
```

Which is identical to this:

```
{{my-component content=appObj bindingConfig="name"}}
{{my-component content=appObj bindingConfig="Darth Meow"}}
```

Considering there is no `Darth Meow` property on the `appObj` (or `content`), ember is behaving as expected.

What you want is this:

```
{{my-component content=appObj bindingConfig="name"}}
{{my-component content=this bindingConfig="nickName"}}
```

The second component will now look up the `nickName` property on your `controller`.